# my best friend who is a man called me a little doodle. What does this mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

My best male friend called me a little doodle.  What does this moniker "little doodle" mean?

Comment: I think the only way you can know what he means by this is to ask him.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I want to phrase my question to him correctly.  He has not for the 3 years that we have known each other called me by anything, but my real name.

Comment: Strangely enough there is an archaic definition of 'doodle' that means  ["a foolish or silly person."](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/doodle) The 5th definition. Not sure how likely it is that he knew what the word could mean, or maybe he was using it in an endearingly teasing manner. Do you have more of the context that your conversation was in? What was his tone of voice?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doodle

"The word doodle first appeared in the early 17th century to mean a fool or simpleton. German variants of the etymon include Dudeltopf, Dudentopf, Dudenkopf, Dude and Dödel. American English dude may be a derivation of doodle."

Comment: I suspect it was intended as a term of endearment (like "my little chickadee"), though perhaps one with a belittling subcontext.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is used in Season 5, Episode 8 of "The Simpsons," in reference to a cheese doodle being used as fishing bait ("Godspeed, little doodle"). If your male friend likes the Simpsons or is of a certain age, it might be an allusion to this, and therefore a term of endearment.